# Wiring up 3 alternative power supplies for a new system

Tags: power-supply, power, design

A new system requires 3 alternative power supplies:

1. On-board PSU 110V~ to 12V=
2. Onboard 12V= battery
3. External 12V= vehicle battery through cigarette lighter socket.

I am looking out for suggestions on how to wire them up.

Comment: What system are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Raymond, but you invest a bit of effort in writing a clear question if you are to avoid wasting your readers' time trying to guess what components you have, what you are trying to build and what "pcs" are. Don't omit words from sentences such as "I" at the start of the last sentence as it is grammatically incorrect and makes it more difficult to read and understand - particularly for non English-speaking readers. There's an [edit] link below your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your equipment is to be powered by an internal 12V battery / internal 12V power supply and occasionally by a 12V vehicle battery.

A Schottky diode would ensure that the power supply and the vehicle battery, with a slightly higher voltage, would override the internal battery.

[image]

A DC barrel jack socket (with battery disconnect) would be required on the equipment to input power from the vehicle battery and, at the same time, disconnect the negative line from the internal battery and power supply. 
A cable, with a cigarette lighter plug at one end and a DC barrel jack plug at the other, would also be required for the purpose.

Comment: The unit has both batteries and a a/c/ to  d/c/  power supply both internal to the  unit. However only one is used at a time while all three are some how tied together to be used as needed. Hope this helps RS

Comment: Hi Raymond Secrist, Thank you for the information. My answer has been modified to suit.

Comment: Thank you for your help, solution much easier than I thought it would be, again thank you  RS

Comment: You are most welcome, RS!

Comment: Thank you, Raymond.